# CSS child parent div

Tags: css

how Parent div prevents the div child from expansion outside?
Like  div p content div c.
I won't prevent div c outside div p.

```
// html file
<div id="p" style="">
<div id="c">

</div>
</div>


// css file

#p {
    border: 3px solid #FC3;
    border-radius: 20px;    

}

#c {
    background-color: #0F3;
    position:absolute;

}
```

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use overflow:hidden:
 `<div id="c" style="overflow:hidden;"/>`